# How to assign a friendly name to a port number in Linux?

Tags: linux

I'd like to assign a friendly name to a port number, how should I do it?

For example: I'd like "0.0.0.0:my-service-name" translates to "0.0.0.0:1234"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, by adding your port definition to [`/etc/services`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/services.5.html). For a TCP service, you’d add

```
my-service-name    1234/tcp
```

Once that’s done, you’ll be able to write “0.0.0.0:my-service-name” instead of “0.0.0.0:1234”.

The canonical list of services is maintained [by the IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), but you can add local definitions; you might even see a “# Local services” comment at the end of your `/etc/services` file already.

Comment: It's important to note that this will only work on your local machine. If you want some other computers on the network to use that name, you'll have to modify `/etc/services` on those machines.

Comment: @user431397 it won’t, `/etc/services` is a conffile (see `/var/lib/dpkg/info/netbase.conffiles`). More generally, `/etc` belongs to the system administrator, it’s a bug if a package doesn’t preserve changes made there.